# C# MongoDB index causes weird duplicate exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

we have a problem with our indexes. We have an index on our emails but it throws errors like such:

```
> db.User.insert({email: "hell33o@gmail.com", "_id" : BinData(3,"iKyq6FvBCdd54TdxxX0JhA==")})

WriteResult({
"nInserted" : 0,
"writeError" : {
    "code" : 11000,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: placetobe.User.$email_text dup key: { : \"com\", : 0.6666666666666666 }"
}
```

})

when we have the index created with our C# driver like this

Created by C# with:

```
CreateIndexOptions options = new CreateIndexOptions {Unique = true};
        _collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<User>.IndexKeys.Text(_ => _.email), options);
```

resulted in

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "unique" : true,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "email_text",
    "ns" : "placetobe.User",
    "weights" : {
        "email" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 2
}
```

but if we create it with the MongoDB console like this it works:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "unique" : true,
    "key" : {
        "email" : 1
    },
    "name" : "email_1",
    "ns" : "placetobe.User"
}
```

I don't understand the difference between the two indexes, but they have an effect on our DB. We also have problems with a Collectin that saves names. we get duplicate exceptions on "Molly" if we try to insert "Molli". With the emails is seems to give us errors whenever we have two "gmail" emails in the collection or two ".com" emails etc.

This is a University project and we have to turn it in tomorrow. we're really in trouble, help would be much appreciated

Comment: What mongo version and what command are you using to create the index in the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want your email to be a text Index. Text indices allow you to search large amounts of text in MongoDB like if you were parsing through comments or something. All you want is to make sure your emails aren't duplicated so you should use an ascending or descending index.

```
CreateIndexOptions options = new CreateIndexOptions {Unique = true};    
_collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<User>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.email), options)
```

Comment: Years later, but still helpful. : )